# Determine Path Used by R (RStudio) After file.choose()

Tags: r, import, rstudio, filepath

Is there a way to determine what file path was used after loading a file into RStudio using `file.choose()`? I was trying to use an absolute file path to load a file, to which RStudio tells me:

```
Error: `path` does not exist:
```

I suspect this is occurring because I may have done some damage to my R setup recently (I had issues after installing the latest R, and tried to troubleshoot with online support to correct my `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` files, but I am NOT a programmer).  So now R is not recognizing the absolute path to my file, and I'm forced to use `file.choose()` as a workaround.  Ideally, I'd like to see what path `file.choose()` used so that I can

A) use the correct path reference, and

B) have a better sense of what is going on with my R setup

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yy-ismDUkkQ

Comment: the error says that you have not created an object, likely a character string of the file path, called `path` I don't see how this has anything to do with whether the file actually exists or if you have the wrong file path

Comment: @rawr I'm not sure I understand your response, as I was using a character string in the `read_excel()` function. The exact command I ran was `Books_Report <- read_excel("\\ELSPHIDATP04VA/COMBSD/Pricing Initiatives/Books/General Books References/Book Reports/HS Books Report_20180822.xlsx")` and the result error was `Error: path does not exist: \ELSPHIDATP04VA/COMBSD/Pricing Initiatives/Books/General Books References/Book Reports/HS Books Report_20180822.xlsx’`. No where did I reference a variable called `path`.

Comment: it's in your question.. I'm not sure what platform you are using, but I doubt `\\ELSPHIDATP04VA/...` is a valid file path. it should look like `C://path/file.xlsx` or `./path/file.xlsx` or `~/path/file.xlsx` or similar